# How to glow a UIButtons in sequence

Tags: iphone, puzzle, memory

I am working on a memory based matching puzzle game. For that I need to glow buttons in a sequence that's generated randomly.

I am glowing the buttons by changing its background images. I'd like to get the buttons to glow in a randomly defined sequence, then have the player enter that sequence in.

Game Screen for better understanding

[image]

After flashing of coloured light

[image]

How do I properly glow the buttons from the sequence?

Comment: So, what's your problem? Didn't really get it from your question. While I know nothing about iPhone programming, I'd be able to help out with the basic algorithm for the game for example. Try to be as specific as you can and then put that into your question's caption. For example "How do I change sprite colors?" or "What algorithm to use?" or something similar. Also some images might hep a lot if your problem is visual.

Comment: -1 for obfuscated "how do I program".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one looking for answer can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646435/how-to-glow-a-uibutton-randomly-from-a-sequence-of-buttons-continuously)

Hope it helps someone

Thanks all for concerns and suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

*Okay, I'm assuming you've got general issues with game logic and how to implement it properly (i.e. it not working as expected). If that isn't the case, let me know and I'll remove this again.*

While I can't help you with the actual code implementation, from what I got from your code you might have chosen an implementation strategy, that makes it slightly more difficulty than actually required.

The following is to be considered pseudo code. I'm pretty sure you should be able to get it working though:

- First of all, you'll need one array or list (or some other collection) supporting either FIFO or full random access.
- To start you generate the pattern and fill your array. In my example I'm going to use a character array:

  ```
  char solution[256];

  for (int i = 0; i < solution_length; i++)
      solution[i] = rand() % number_of_buttons;
  ```
- This gets me an array with the solution. For simplification, let's say we've got the buttons one through four, then the array could contain `1, 2, 3, 4`, which would essentially mean that the solution is hitting the buttons in exact that order.
- Checking player input and playing the animation now are pretty much similar. You'll either need some index (to know which entry is next) or you drop the very first entry in your list (which might be problematic in case you'd like to repeat a pattern upon failure; you could just work with a copy as well though).
- Basically, wen it's time to light up a button, you have a look at the array to see what's the next button. In the example above, first will be `1`, so your code triggers the first button lighting up. Then your index is moved to the second entry (or the first entry is dropped altogether).
- Now you're having a look at the next entry, which would be `1` again (and after this it would be `3`).
- You just keep repeating this process.
- If you're lighting up the buttons, once you reach the end you're done.
- If you're checking player input and you reach the end, the player has won. If some entry doesn't match the input, you know that the player used the wrong key.
- Organizing the game logic like this makes it rather easy to implement different game modes. For example, your *rapid mode* simply won't wait forever for the player to hit a button. If they don't tap in time, you just assume failure - done.

Comment: Excellent answer with good logic, but how to implement this, I am in need of some sample code, ideally Objective-C, thanks for your efforts anyhow :)

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe someone else can work with this, but keep in mind that this site is for problem solving, it's less about "code for me". :)

Comment: Haha,no problem. Thanks for your concern anyhow. I am just an average coder and I have just started gaming for iPhone, which is pretty new to me, so get ready for many questions here :P